# Redis not starting on boot with systemd but works with manual start

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, redis

I have installed redis on Ubuntu 16.04 according to the [digialtocean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04). It uses systemd and should start on boot.

I can start redis from cli

```
sudo systemctl start redis
```

and it works with no error or issue. However when I reboot, redis fails to start. I tried several things I found via googling, nothing worked so far:

- setting Type=forking or Type=notify (or leaving it away entirely like in the guide)
- Adding LimitNOFILE=65536 to get rid of an error (which it does but still fails to load)

There is no clear error in journalctl:

```
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: Starting Redis In-Memory Data Store...
Lubuntu-16-04 redis-server[799]: 799:C 12 Jul 10:34:12.532 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
Lubuntu-16-04 redis-server[799]: 799:C 12 Jul 10:34:12.532 # Redis version=4.0.10, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=799, just started
Lubuntu-16-04 redis-server[799]: 799:C 12 Jul 10:34:12.532 # Configuration loaded
Lubuntu-16-04 redis-server[799]: 799:C 12 Jul 10:34:12.532 * supervised by systemd, will signal readiness
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: Started Redis In-Memory Data Store.
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Unit entered failed state.
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: Stopped Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

This block is repeated 5 times in the log and then at the end of the log this message appears:

```
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: redis.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Lubuntu-16-04 systemd[1]: Failed to start Redis In-Memory Data Store.
```

In the redis log I see this:

```
Creating Server TCP listening socket 192.168.XX.XXX:6379: bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

I want to allow remote connection, that is why I also bind to "external" IP. Is this causing redis to fail startup? But it works fine when starting manually. What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systemd config needs to be changed and IMHO is wrong as shown on digitalocean.

The systemd unit configurations `After` target needs to be changed:

```
[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network-online.target
```

In the guide it is `After=network.target` which according to [this guide](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/) has very little meaning, eg. the network is probably not yet fully ready and hence binding to external IP fails.